# Metalanaguage to describe the Model from MVC to generate identical client and server side code

Tags: javascript, sqlite, model, client-server, metalanguage

I am looking for a powerful meta-language to describa behaviour for an application i intend to use in offline mode (google-gears + javascript) and server side sqlite + (php/ruby/java etc) and looking for a good format to describe the model's behaviour which can be easily converted to the target languages.
Am I completely off track, and there is a much better way?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)?  GWT allows you to write server side Java objects which get translated into Javascript for you.  This allows you to not deal with the browser quirks at all.
I'm not sure how well integrated the Gears and GWT projects are, however.  If it isn't integrated yet, I'm sure it will be in fairly short order.

Edit:  This is probably more of an alternate way of doing what you're looking for, rather than a suggestion for a meta language.

Answer (score 1):

This may be out of your scope, but maybe you should consider [sproutcore](http://www.sproutcore.com/).  From what I understand, it's a bundled up MVC architecture that can be backend-agnostic.

I don't have much experience with it, but it sounds like some of the consumers (apple's MobileMe for instance) want to do the same thing you do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using [Script#](http://www.codeplex.com/scriptsharp)?